# Can we create a replica set for Zalenium Hub

Tags: kubernetes-helm, zalenium

I am trying to replicate zalenium hub using kubernetes but I am facing issues. Single zalenium hub is working fine. If I added replica count more than 1 then it's showing 403 Forbidden, 502 Badgateway, No VNC..etc in zalanium live preview page(http://zalenium:port/admin/grid/live)

It's showing sometimes 502 Badgateway in live preview page and 403 Forbidden, No VNC in zalenium containers.

Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Here is my kubernetes deployment file while running.

````
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    app: zalenium
    chart: zalenium-0.1.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: releasename
  name: zalenium
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "6472109"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/zalenium
  uid: e37db0c3-97de-11e9-b164-001a4a000076
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 2147483647
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2147483647
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zalenium
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: zalenium
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - start
        env:
        - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_CPU_REQUEST
          value: 250m
        - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_CPU_LIMIT
          value: 1000m
        - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST
          value: 500Mi
        - name: ZALENIUM_KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT
          value: 2Gi
        - name: DESIRED_CONTAINERS
          value: "2"
        - name: MAX_DOCKER_SELENIUM_CONTAINERS
          value: "10"
        - name: SELENIUM_IMAGE_NAME
          value: elgalu/selenium
        - name: VIDEO_RECORDING_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        - name: SCREEN_WIDTH
          value: "1440"
        - name: SCREEN_HEIGHT
          value: "900"
        - name: MAX_TEST_SESSIONS
          value: "1"
        - name: NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT
          value: "600000"
        - name: DEBUG_ENABLED
          value: "false"
        - name: SEND_ANONYMOUS_USAGE_INFO
          value: "true"
        - name: TZ
          value: UTC
        - name: KEEP_ONLY_FAILED_TESTS
          value: "false"
        - name: RETENTION_PERIOD
          value: "3"
        image: dosel/zalenium:3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: zalenium
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4444
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 500Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/seluser/videos
          name: videos
        - mountPath: /tmp/mounted
          name: data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: zalenium
      serviceAccountName: zalenium
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: videos
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: data```

Expecting it should be run like a single zalenium hub.
````

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, Zalenium works only with one hub, so only one replica is allowed.

Comment: Yes, got to know from Zalenium slack channel. 
Thanks.